# Is it possible to turn boost mode in highcharts only when client's browser starts to jank?

Tags: javascript, browser, highcharts, web-performance

I have a dynamically updated chart with animation that can produce jank in some conditions on weak machines.
I'd like to use boost mode, but I don't want to abandon animation on the majority of clients.
Is there any way to determine where the jank or a lack of the client's processor time is present. And once Highcharts gets this state -> boost mode is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could define jenk as dropping frames. Let's say you want to minimally animate 25 frames a second, anything below that is a dropped frame.

If 100 frames are dropped then give up on animating high charts but if 200 frames are fine then reset dropped frames to 0.

You can adjust the rules of what is too much jenk and give up but the rules below describe rules in the code below:

```
const frameDetector = (
  (minFPS,alertWhen)=>{
    var callBacks = [];
    var dropped = 0;
    var passed = 0;
    const detect = last => {
      if((Date.now()-last)>(1000/minFPS)){
        console.log("dropped frame");
        dropped++;
      }else{
        passed++;
      }
      if(dropped>alertWhen){
        callBacks.forEach(callback=>callback());
        return;
      }
      if(passed>(2*alertWhen)){
        //doing well, didn't drop frames for a while so reset dropped
        console.log("Doing well, reset dropped");
        dropped = 0;
        passed=0;
      }
      last = Date.now();
      requestAnimationFrame(()=>detect(last));
    }
    detect(Date.now());
    return {
      addListener:x=>callBacks.push(x),
      removeListener:x=>callBacks=callBacks.filter(cb=>cb!==x)
    }
  }
)(25,100);//minimum 25 frames per second, maximum 100 dropped frames

//handler function to handle when browser start dropping too many frames
const whenToManyFramesAreDropped = ()=>{
  //turn off boost:
  //https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.enabled
  console.log("Dropping too many frames, go to power mode");
};
frameDetector.addListener(whenToManyFramesAreDropped);
```

Comment: Just additional info regarding Highcharts: boost module can be switched on/off using this property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.enabled

Comment: @KamilKulig Thank you, I'll add it. Think that OP knows how to switch boost off but doesn't know to detect when to switch it off.